# mod rewrite right markup

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expression, repeat

I have mod rewrite expressions in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&cat=$2&ac=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?start=$1&lang=$2&cat=$3&ac=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&cat=$2&bc=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?start=$1&lang=$2&cat=$3&bc=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&cat=$2&cc=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?start=$1&lang=$2&cat=$3&cc=$4 [L]
```

but GET's of links are wrong because of same (repeating) conditions (for ac, bc, cc).

I have this kind of solution, but don't like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([x]+[0-9a-z]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&cat=$2&ac=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([x]+[0-9a-z]+)$ /index.php?start=$1&lang=$2&cat=$3&ac=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([y]+[0-9a-z]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&cat=$2&bc=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([y]+[0-9a-z]+)$ /index.php?start=$1&lang=$2&cat=$3&bc=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([z]+[0-9a-z]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&cat=$2&cc=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/(am|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([z]+[0-9a-z]+)$ /index.php?start=$1&lang=$2&cat=$3&cc=$4 [L]
```

What is right solution for this.

Comment: of course www.mysite.com/am/pr/ac,  www.mysite.com/2/am/pr/ac, www.mysite.com/am/pr/bc,  www.mysite.com/0/am/pr/bc, www.mysite.com/am/pr/cc,  www.mysite.com/3/am/pr/cc                  For last solution:       www.mysite.com/am/pr/xac,  www.mysite.com/2/am/pr/xac, www.mysite.com/am/pr/ybc,  www.mysite.com/0/am/pr/ybc, www.mysite.com/am/pr/zcc,  www.mysite.com/3/am/pr/zcc

Comment: instead of ac, bc, cc can be: red, summer, forwoman as for example clothes parameters. All this for product filtering. www.mysite.com/2/am/pr/blue/winter/forman

Comment: I'm not sure what your input and expected output are, but in the first set of rules, only your first two rules will match.  In each following pair of rules, they will try to match exactly the same thing, which will fail.  Having two rules match exactly the same thing, without conditions, won't work in general... only the first will apply.

Comment: Yes I know but can't make conditions.

Comment: Show what you want the input and expected output to be (ie, what the user requests, and what the server provides), otherwise we don't really know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: ac, bc, cc can be color name, size, brand (or can use some numbers) etc. For example if we have clothes ac can be color(red, blue, green), bc can be brand (soliver, kavalli, boss), cc can be size (45, 48, 58). We must filter clothes. Show all boss 45 size clothes.   www.mysite.com/am/pr/boss/45